# Android: Download File only if changed

Tags: android, http

I want to write a android application which needs data from the web. This information is stored in a json-file. The data from the json-file is saved on the device. To keep it up to date, I need to check for changes in the file every hour.

As the remote File can get quite large I want to download it only if it is different from the version which was previously downloaded. I thought about using the Last-Modified-Header of HTTP for this.

I came up with the following workflow (pseudo-code):

- `data = null; data_timestamp = null;`
- Every hour repeat:

  - Issue a HTTP Head-Request to the URL and option `new_timestamp` from `Last-Modified` Header.
  - If either `data==null` or `new_timestamp > data_timestamp` then

    - Issue a normal HTTP-Request to the URL
    - Save to `data` and set `data_timestamp = new_timestamp`

Do you think this is a reasonable approach? I could use the `if-modified-since` HTTP Header to get the data only if it has changed since the last download. This would save me one request. If it has changed, a body containing the new data is provided, if it hasn't, the body is empty.

I also thought about using ETags, as I typically want to download if the file has new content (and not if the modified-date has changed), but my webserver (nginx) doesn't support the creation of etags and I don't want to involve another layer on the server-side for performance-reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as described by me above: Download the file by using the `if-modified-since` HTTP Header. The `ngnix` webserver can be configured to return the right information regarding this header.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) instead of relying on `HTTP HEAD`.  They are [supported in `javax.ws.rs.core` with the `EntityTag` class](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/EntityTag.html).

You can see a [Java-based example using Spring](http://www.infoq.com/articles/etags) to help explain some of the concepts as well.

Comment: I already had a look at ETags, but my webserver (ngnix) currently doesn't support them out of the box. But thanks for the hint.